# can I use body two times?

Tags: css, css-specificity

I have a CSS file with some div styles and this CSS has a body, like this:

css1.css

```
body{
 background-color:#000;
}
#div1{
...
}
#div2{
...
}
```

in a page I want to use some divs that are in css1.css but with a different body color.
So I create another css for this:

css2.css

```
body{
 background-color:#fff;
}
```

so in this page I have:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css2.css">
```

css1.css has a body and css2 too, is it right? Can I have any problem doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can!

Although you may need to look at **css selector specificity**: 
https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/web/2.3.0/org.tizen.mobile.web.appprogramming/html/guide/w3c_guide/dom_guide/html_priorities_css.htm. Here is a more illustrated resource:

[image]

from https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

The specificity depends on the number of tags, ids, classes, pseudo-classes etc that are contained in your selectors. If there is a tie between selectors then the order matters.

Those two selectors (for body) have the same specificity (=0001) so the second one will override the common properties of the first.

Or in other words the body background-color will be #fff :). If that is useful to you is a different question.

Comment: @RickJoe css specificity is one of the most important things to take into account for css :) you are very welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need all that, you can simply set different background colours to the divs. You can give them different IDs or classes and work your css around that.

HTML:

```
<div id="one">this is div one</div>
<div id="two">this is div two</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#one { background-color: blue; }
div#two { background-color: red; }
```

You could also change your body with different classes on different pages that consume the same CSS. I hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 3):

It is OK.  The last declaration will take precedence over the first, assuming the selectors are the same.